# Что лучше для работы с XML в PHP?

Tags: xml, php

Задача такая: нужно добавлять и удалять в XML с помощью PHP. Как проще реализовать это?

Comment: @Royal, не забывайте принимать ответы.

Answer (score 1):

если только добавлять и удалять - simplexml...
О нем можно почитать *[здесь](http://www.realcoding.net/articles/php5-kak-rabotat-s-xml-cherez-simplexml.html)*

Answer (score 1):

Я использую [DOMDocument](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php).
Там все достаточно просто:

```
$domxml = new DOMDocument();
$domxml->loadXML("<root><elem /></root>"); // Подгружаем XML в виде строки
$domxml->load("localfile.xml"); // или локальный xml-файл
$domxml->load("http://domen.com/file.xml"); // или удаленный xml-файл

$root = $domxml->createElement("root"); // Создаем корневой элемент
$root->appendChild("elem"); // Добавляем ребятенка корневому элементу

$domxml->saveXML(); // Выводим XML на экран
```

У меня есть класс для работы с XML, немного расширяющий базовые функции. Могу поделиться.